# Unstable citing behaviour of Latex in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

It seems that I am having trouble with unstable citing behavior in Overleaf.

**Problem**: I want to cite some references, but I got the warning *'Citation XX on page YY undefined on input line ZZ'* and the citation failed (see picture below)

**The catch**: I know, normally this warning comes up when you mistyped the citation key or the citation is not included in the reference.bib file.
However, sometimes the citation does get the above warning, but at other times it does just work fine. Today, I got the warning for one citation (of which I three-double check the key and my reference file). I went to a meeting, I came back, recompiled without changing anything and the citation just worked fine.

I do work in an adapted article template, so I did not write the template myself. I hope you can help me in finding out what is going on, or maybe I am just turning crazy..

Thanks a lot!

[By the way, the below code is just a dummy code. I cannot share my actual written code becasue of intelectual property rules]

Screenshot of the failed citation of Thiese:

[image: Failed citation of Thiese]

The code of my main file:

```
\input{packages/xjenza-preamble.tex}

% Front matter
\title{A nice title}
\articleType{A nice article type}%Research Article, Review Article, Research Note, News Article...
\author{Some nice authors}
\authorAnnotation{Some nice annotation}
\correspondanceName{Some nice name}
\correspondanceMail{Some nice email address}
% This goes in the header, in case the full title is too long
\shortTitle{ }

% \selfCitation{Borg, J. et al.\ (2022).\newblock {\em Xjenza Online}, \pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastPage}.}

% Bibliography file
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Insert additional packages here
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%% Do not edit %%%%%
\def\firstpage{1}
\newcounter{pagna}
\setcounter{pagna}{\firstpage}
\setcounter{page}{\firstpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
    \label{firstpage}

    \abstrac{\lipsum[1-11]
    }
        
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    I would really like to cite this guy: \parencite{aniceguy} and a second nice guy \parencite{asecondniceguy}. I also would like to mention \parencite{Thiese}, but sometimes the citation does not work properly. 
   
    % List all citations
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
    
    % Balance columns on last page
    \balance
    
     
    % For header on first page
    \label{lastPage}
\end{document}
```

The code of the reference.bib file:

```
%  Formatting guide:
%
%  (at)article{key,
%    author  = {Surname, A. and Surname, B. C. and Surname, D.},
%    title   = {Titles are Written in Title Case},
%    note    = {Something Special about the Publication},
%    journal = {Full Name of the Journal in Title Case},
%    year    = {2000},
%    volume  = {1},
%    number  = {1},
%    pages   = {1--5},
%    url     = {http://optional.com}
%  }


@ARTICLE{aniceguy,
    AUTHOR = {Nice},
    TITLE = {A very nice title that I would like to cite},
    YEAR = {2022},
    JOURNAL = {A very nice year},
    VOLUME = {1},
    PAGES = {1-10}
}

@ARTICLE{asecondniceguy,
    AUTHOR = {Nice Second },
    TITLE = {A second nice title that I would like to cite},
    YEAR = {2022},
    JOURNAL = {A very nice year},
    VOLUME = {1},
    PAGES = {1-10}
}

@ARTICLE{Thiese,
    AUTHOR = {Thiese, M.S., Hegmann, K.T., Wood, E.M. et al.},
    TITLE = {Prevalence of low back pain by anatomic location and intensity in an occupational population},
    YEAR = {2014},
    JOURNAL = {BMC Musculoskelet Disord},
    VOLUME = {15},
    PAGES = {283}
}
```

And the code of the xjenza-preamble.tex file:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,floatfix,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{article}%twoside
\usepackage{packages/xjenza}
\usepackage{datetime,tabularx,multirow,subfigure,dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum,cuted,setspace,enumerate}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{colortbl,color}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul,longtable}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textgreek, upgreek}% these should be before amssymb, amsthm and amsmath
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{placeins}
\setlist{noitemsep}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[scale=1.03]{inconsolata}
\usepackage[                % For hyperlinks and PDF document links
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue!60!black,
    citecolor=blue!60!black,
    urlcolor=green!50!black,
    bookmarks,
    bookmarksopen,
    bookmarksdepth=3,
    pdfstartview={XYZ null null null},
    pdfcreator={Created with vim+LaTeX}]{hyperref}

\usepackage[                % For clever in-document references
    nameinlink,
    noabbrev]{cleveref}

\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    % Correct PDF hyperlinks to figures
% self inserted usepackages
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

% Maltese Letters
\newcommand \mc {\.c}
\newcommand \mC {\.C}
\newcommand \mg {\.g}
\newcommand \mG {\.G}
\newcommand \mh {{\leavevmode\rlap{\kern-.7pt\={\empty}}}h}
\newcommand \mhi {$\hbar$}
\newcommand \mH {\leavevmode\rlap{\raisebox{-.8pt}{\={\empty}}}H\llap{\raisebox{-.8pt}{\={\empty}}}}
\newcommand \mHi {\leavevmode\rlap{\kern-.3pt\raisebox{-.7pt}{\={\empty}}}H\llap{\raisebox{-.7pt}{\={\empty}}}}
\newcommand \mz {\.z}
\newcommand \mZ {\.Z}


% Montserrat for bold
\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\small\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont{\oldtextbf{#1}}}}


%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{flushend}%balancing cols

%--Settings for the modified apa citation style--:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%
%  This method uses the Biblatex package with the biber backend.
%  After installing the Biblatex package install the
%  biblatex-apa citation style. Afterwords, replace the `apa.bbx'
%  and `apa.cbx' files in the biblatex-apa directory, ex:
%  /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-apa
%  with the files present in the packages folder.

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false,maxcitenames=1,uniquelist=false,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,style=apa,texencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{% suppressing the month
  \clearfield{month}
  \clearfield{day}
}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\setlength\bibhang{2em}
%---

%--Item spacing: add \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt,
%--parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt] to use--:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt}
%---

%--New commands--:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
\newcommand{\udt}[3]{#1^{#2}_{\phantom{#2}#3}}
\newcommand{\dut}[3]{#1_{#2}^{\phantom{#2}#3}}
\newcommand{\dudt}[4]{#1_{#2\phantom{#3}#4}^{\phantom{#2}#3}}
%---

% This removes 'n.d.' from misc entries which have no year field associated with them
\DeclareLabeldate[misc]{%
    \field{year}
}

% Suppress fancyhdr warning
\setlength{\headheight}{12.49998pt}

%--Setting section headers--::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        \titleformat{\section}{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
        \titleformat{\subsection}{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
%---


%--paragraph spacing--::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
\parindent 10 pt
\parskip 0 pt
%---

%::::::::::::::::::::::::--End of xjenza-preamble.tex--::::::::::::::::::::::::::%
```

The code of the xjenza.sty file:

```
% Copyright (C) 2014 William Hicklin. Last revised 04/03/2015.

% This is xjenza.sty, a LaTeX style for the Maltese Journal Xjenza.
%
% This package is supplied with a preamble file named `xjenza-preamble.tex'. This
% file contains a list on commonly used packages in this journal. There are also
% some new commands and redefinitions which might come in handy for some papers.
%
% This package is also supplied with a `xjenza-main.tex' file which can be
% changed to `xjenza-Vol-Issue.tex'. This file is where the document is written.
%
% The xjenza package should contain: packages/xjenza.sty, packages/xjenza-
% preamble.tex, packages/apa.bbx, packages/apa.cbx, xjenza-main.tex.
%
% The `apa.bbx' and `apa.cbx' files should be interchanged with those of the
% biblatex-apa style. On Linux systems this is normally found in
% /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex-apa
%
% If you find any bugs in the style files, or omissions in the documentation,
% please report them to: E-mail whic0001@um.edu.mt


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  Include required packages.
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{cmbright}


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  Setting margins
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\setlength{\paperwidth}{597.50787pt}
\setlength{\paperheight}{845.04684pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{497.92322pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{497.92322pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{695.41338pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-21.33955pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-21.33955pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-28.45274pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{25.0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{10.0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{30.0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{4.0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10.0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{14.22636pt}


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  Set captions type-setting.
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

% removed "margin=10pt," (29/07/2015)
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf,margin=0.1in]{caption}


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  Settting global variables and definitions
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\def\keywords#1{\gdef\@keywords{#1}}
\def\shortTitle#1{\gdef\@shortTitle{#1}}
%\def\doi#1{\gdef\@doi{#1}}
\def\articleType#1{\gdef\@articleType{#1}}
\def\authorAnnotation#1{\gdef\@authorAnnotation{#1}}
\def\correspondanceName#1{\gdef\@correspondanceName{#1}}
\def\correspondanceMail#1{\gdef\@correspondanceMail{#1}}
\def\correspondanceNames#1{\gdef\@correspondanceNames{#1}}
\def\abstrac#1{\gdef\@abstrac{#1}}
\def\selfCitation#1{\gdef\@selfCitation{#1}}


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  The \keywords{} command
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\newcommand{\keywordscom}[1]{%

\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{
\noindent {\bfseries Keywords} #1\\
}
}


%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
%  The \maketitle command
%%%:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
% the following fiedls are required
%
% \title{}
% \doi{}
% \articleType{} %(Research Article, Review Article, Research Note...)
% \authors{}
% \authorAnnotations{}
% \abstract{}
% \correspondenceName{}
% \correspondenceMail{}
%
% the following fiedls are optional
%
% \shortTitle{}
% \keywords{}
\clearpage% new page for new paper

%- New headers::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
\pagestyle{fancy}

\ifx\@shortTitle\empty
    \fancyhead[LE]{\arabic{pagna}\stepcounter{pagna}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\@title}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\@title}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\arabic{pagna}\stepcounter{pagna}}
\else
    \fancyhead[LE]{\arabic{pagna}\stepcounter{pagna}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\@shortTitle}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\@shortTitle}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\arabic{pagna}\stepcounter{pagna}}
\fi

%\lfoot{\small{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont{\bfseries\href{https://doi.org/\@doi}{\@doi}}}}
\rfoot{\small{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont{\bfseries\href{https://laevo-exoskeletons.com}{www.laevo-exoskeletons.com}}}}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the header underline
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %remove the footer underline

%- Keeping footnotes on the left side of the page:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%- Setting page style for title page::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
    \lhead{\@selfCitation}
    \rhead{\stepcounter{pagna}}
    \rfoot{}
    \chead{}
    \cfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[l]{
    \ifx\@correspondanceName\empty
    %No correspondance given
    \else
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0mm}{}\footnotesize\emph{*Correspondence to}: \@correspondanceName{} (\href{mailto:\@correspondanceMail}{\@correspondanceMail})\end{adjustwidth}
    \fi
    % {\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\large\bfseries{© 2022 Xjenza Online}}
    }
}

%\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
%   \lhead{\@selfCitation}
%   \rhead{\stepcounter{pagna}}
%   \rfoot{}
%   \chead{}
%   \cfoot{}
%   \fancyfoot[l]{
%   \ifx\@correspondanceNames\empty
%       \ifx\@correspondanceName\empty
%       %No correspondance given
%       \else
%       \begin{adjustwidth}{-0mm}{}\footnotesize\emph{*Correspondence to}: \@correspondanceName{} (\href{mailto:\@correspondanceMail}{\@correspondanceMail})\end{adjustwidth}
%       \fi
%   %No correspondance given
%   \else
%   \begin{adjustwidth}{-0mm}{}\footnotesize\emph{*Correspondence to}: \@correspondanceNames{}
%   \end{adjustwidth}
%   \fi
%   \large{\textbf{\copyright\,2017 Xjenza Online}}
%   }
%}

%- Title page:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\begin{strip}
    \vspace{-2cm}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2mm}{}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
%       Xjenza Online: Science Journal of the Malta Chamber of Scientists\\
%       \href{https://www.xjenza.org}{\nolinkurl{www.xjenza.org}}\\
        %\ifx\@doi\empty
        %No DOI given
        %\else
        %DOI: \href{https://doi.org/\@doi}{\nolinkurl{\@doi}}
        %\fi
        \\\\
        \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{r} \includegraphics[width=.22\textwidth]{logo.png} \end{tabular} 
    \end{tabular*}\end{adjustwidth}
    \noindent\emph{\@articleType}\\

        \noindent\Large{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\bfseries{\@title}}\\

        \noindent\normalsize{\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\bfseries{\@author}}\\
    \textit\@authorAnnotation
    \vspace{2mm}
\end{strip}

\thispagestyle{firststyle}

% The following will draw a line below the abstract if only an abstract is present. If either the keywords are only present or both the keywords and the abstract are present, the line is drawn below the keywords.

\ifx\@abstrac\empty
    % No abstract is given
\else
        \noindent {\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\bfseries{Abstract. }}\@abstrac\\
    \vspace{-1ex}
\fi

\ifx\@keywords\empty
    % No keywords given
    \ifx\@abstrac\empty
        % No abstract is given
    \else
        \noindent \rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}
    \fi
\else
        \noindent {\fontfamily{Montserrat-LF}\selectfont\bfseries{Keywords: }}\@keywords\\
    \noindent \rule{\columnwidth}{0.5pt}
\fi

%\vspace{1mm}

%- Default settings:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\keywords{}

% Begins a refsection for separating bibliographies by papers.
% The \paperbib command must be used at the end of each paper where the bibliography
% will be printed.
}

%- Default settings:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

\keywords{}
\shortTitle{}
\abstrac{}
```

Comment: Sorry but your example is way too long to debug. Check the blg-file for an error message.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be better, if you provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407), i.e. all relevant code in one file.

Comment: and your author list is wrong: `Thiese, M.S., Hegmann, K.T., Wood, E.M. et al.},` should be `Thiese, M.S. and Hegmann, K.T. and Wood, E.M. and other}`,

Comment: "I cannot share my actual written code becasue of intelectual property rules" You can replace _every_ word with "abc" so this is no reason not to provide a sensible example. If you do not need the `float` package to show the problem, do not include it (twice!!) in the example. If you do not need `Montserrat-LF` font to show the problem, do not use it. similarly you should be able to delete 90% of the code posted while still checking it does show the problem